# Упростить код reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как можно упростить и сделать проще? Я не хочу создавать множество useState для хранения данных, есть ли другие варианты? Данные обновляются из input OnChange.

```
const [ errorBox, setErrorBox ] = useState('')
const [ isLoadingSubmit, setLoadingSubmit ] = useState(false)

    const [ fieldFirstName, setFieldFirstName ] = useState('')
    const [ fieldLogin, setFieldLogin ] = useState('')
    const [ fieldMail, setFieldMail ] = useState('')
    const [ fieldPassword, setFieldPassword ] = useState('')
    const [ fieldRePassword, setFieldRePassword ] = useState('')

    const [ errorFieldFirstName, setErrorFieldFirstName ] = useState('')
    const [ errorFieldLogin, setErrorFieldLogin ] = useState('')
    const [ errorFieldMail, setErrorFieldMail ] = useState('')
    const [ errorFieldPassword, setErrorFieldPassword ] = useState('')
    const [ errorFieldRePassword, setErrorFieldRePassword ] = useState('')

    const onClick = () => {
        setErrorBox ('')
        setErrorFieldFirstName ('')
        setErrorFieldLogin ('')
        setErrorFieldMail ('')
        setErrorFieldPassword ('')
        setErrorFieldRePassword ('')

        if (fieldFirstName === '') setErrorFieldFirstName ('Поле является обязательным.')
        else if (fieldLogin === '') setErrorFieldLogin ('Поле является обязательным.')
        else if (fieldMail === '') setErrorFieldMail ('Поле является обязательным.')
        else if (fieldPassword === '') setErrorFieldPassword ('Поле является обязательным.')
        else if (fieldRePassword === '') setErrorFieldRePassword ('Поле является обязательным.')
        else {
            if (fieldFirstName.length > 32) setErrorFieldFirstName('Размер имени должен быть меньше 32 символов.')
            else if (fieldLogin.length > 32) setErrorFieldLogin('Размер логина должен быть меньше 32 символов.')
            else if (!isValidEmail(fieldMail)) setErrorFieldMail('Почта указана неверно.')
            else if (fieldPassword !== fieldRePassword) {
                setErrorFieldPassword('Пароли не совпадают')
                setErrorFieldRePassword('Пароли не совпадаю')
            }
            else {
                setLoadingSubmit(true)
                sendRequest('account/authorization/register', {
                    'firstname': fieldFirstName,
                    'login': fieldLogin,
                    'mail': fieldMail,
                    'password': fieldPassword
                }, function (response) {
                    setLoadingSubmit(false)
                    if (response.success === true) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("session", response.session)
                        window.location = '/account'
                    }
                    else {
                        if (response.error === 'ACCOUNT_FOUND') setErrorBox('Аккаунт с таким логином уже зарегистрирован')
                        else setErrorBox('Не удалось создать новый аккаунт')
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем вообще ошибки писать в стейт, если они вычисляются простым условием на основе того же стейта. Можно просто передавать в компонент пропс, например isError={fieldLogin.length < 1 || fieldLogin.length > 32 }. Также можно избавиться от состояний всех инпутов, обернув их в форму и брать состояние формы через ref для вычисления ошибок в инпутах.